# Mapping array of numeric strings to integers returns NaN

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert an array of numeric strings to integers, and am seeing something odd.

```js
const ints = ['1','2','3'].map(parseInt);
console.log(ints);
```

The above code returns: `[1, NaN, NaN]`?

The `1` gets parsed correctly, but why are the `2` and `3` getting converted to `NaN`?

Answer (score 0):

**callback is invoked with three arguments: the value of the element, the index of the element, and the Array object being traversed.**

In your case you are actually calling

```
parseInt(1,0)
parseInt(2,1)
parseInt(3,2)
```

where first argument is the arrayElement and second is the **radix** or **base**

1 is valid Base 10 which is represented by radix 0
So 2 is not valid in base 1 and 3 is not valid in base 2

**So the solution is to use arrow function**

```js
const ints = ['1','2','3'].map(num => parseInt(num));
console.log(ints);
```

Comment: The accurate answer is "control the parameters passed to `parseInt`".

Comment: @adiga check out the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

So, I've discovered the answer.

When you pass just a function to `.map`, it passes ALL the arguments on to the function:

```js
var customParseInt = function() {
    console.log('arguments', arguments);
}

var arr = ['1','2','3'];
arr.map(customParseInt);
```

Now, the first time it's called in your `.map`, the first argument is '1' and the second argument is the current index of the array, which is 0.

So for the first array element, you're calling `parseInt('1', 0);`

And for the second array element, you're calling `parseInt('2', 1);` -- again, first argument is the element, second argument is the index of the array.

If you look up the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), the second argument for parseInt is the radix. A radix of 0 does not error (probably because it defaults to a sensible value), but a radix of 1 or 2 makes the parseInt function behave fundamentally differently.

Comment: But it [says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Return_value): "If the radix is smaller than 2 or bigger than 36, and the first non-whitespace character cannot be converted to a number, NaN is returned." ?

Comment: It does indeed say that, and I'm not sure if that's entirely true or slightly misleading personally, but you can test each value yourself in the console.